# test dragging an object in QML with a mouse using QtTest module

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a very simple QML scene with a blue square (size 100x100) placed in the top left corner (x = 0, y = 0). This square is draggable with a mouse.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window

Window {
    id: box
    width: 500
    height: 500
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id: square
        objectName: "square"
        width: 100
        height: 100
        x: 0
        y: 0
        color: "blue"

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            drag.target: square
            drag.axis: Drag.XAndYAxis
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have a simple `main.cpp` in which I instantiate the scene. And then after some delay (100 ms) when the scene is ready, I simulate dragging the square with a mouse.

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QtTest>

void testMoving()
{
    auto window = QGuiApplication::focusWindow();
    Q_ASSERT(window);

    auto square = window->findChild<QQuickItem*>("square");
    Q_ASSERT(square);

    QTest::mousePress(window, Qt::LeftButton, {}, {50, 50});
    QTest::mouseMove(window, {250, 250});
    QTest::mouseRelease(window, Qt::LeftButton, {}, {250, 250});

    qDebug() << square->position();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreationFailed,
        &app, []() { QCoreApplication::exit(-1); },
        Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.loadFromModule("movable", "Main");

    QTimer::singleShot(100, &testMoving);

    return app.exec();
}
```

The code in `testMoving()` is supposed to simulate mouse press at coordinates (50, 50) and dragging to (250, 250). So the coordinates of the square should change from (0, 0) to (200, 200). But it does not work and the square is not moved. The output from `qDebug()` is `QPointF(0,0)`.

I experimented with the code a bit, so I changed the lines to:

```
    QTest::mousePress(window, Qt::LeftButton, {}, {50, 50});
    QTest::mouseMove(window, {200, 200});
    QTest::mouseRelease(window, Qt::LeftButton, {}, {250, 250});
```

Now the result is surprisingly (for me) `QPointF(50,50)`, which is the difference between those 200s and 250s. So the square moved. So I thought "aha!" I must first move the cursor to start of dragging and then release it at the target destination. So I tried:

```
    QTest::mousePress(window, Qt::LeftButton, {}, {50, 50});
    QTest::mouseMove(window, {50, 50});
    QTest::mouseRelease(window, Qt::LeftButton, {}, {250, 250});
```

... and the actual result is again `QPointF(0,0)` instead of the expected `QPointF(200,200)`. WTH is going on? Has anyone an idea how to simulate dragging the square with a mouse using `QtTest`?

Comment: I did my own experiments on the code, and here are a few findings, which are pure observations, I have absolutely no explanation for them. **1-** There has to be at least 11 points between the positions of mousepress and mouse move, doesn't matter which one is bigger. **2-** There has to be at least 1 point between your mousemove and mouserelease, if your mousemove is bigger, your square will move to the left, the opposite is true. Here's an example on how to move square from (0,0) to (200,200): `QTest::mouseMove(window, {1, 1}); QTest::mouseRelease(window, Qt::LeftButton, {}, {201, 201});`

Comment: The difference of 11 points and 1 point can be for both x and y or only one of them. The square will move the difference between mouserelease and mousemove (mouserelease,pos - mousemove.pos)

Comment: Actually I think I may have some explanation. My assumption is that the distance 11 points/pixels is the minimum distance that the mouse needs to travel on screen so that the operation is registered as a dragging action. This would probably make sense...

Comment: oh that makes sense, I'm less confused now, and about the 1 pixel, I noticed when moving the square myself, the cursor seems to get ahead of it, so maybe that's why it does not move when mousemove and mouse release are equal, it kind of follows it, or gets dragged behind it, so if the difference is 0, it does not move

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by @Mihoub Abderrahmene Rayene actually made me realize that this is still a drag operation. And a drag operation requires the mouse to travel a certain minimum distance before it is registered as dragging. Obviously the distance must be bigger than 10 pixels on his system.

So the explanation is this:

1. Mouse button press event gets processed at certain point X.
2. Mouse move event to a point Y which is more distant from X than the minimum required distance (required to start the drag action).
3. Mouse release at point Z of the final mouse destination is needed to finish the dragging.

The final dragged distance then will be the distance between points Y and Z.

PS: The minimum required distance can probably be obtained from https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstylehints.html#startDragDistance-prop

Comment: this cleared things up, so I tried making an example if it helps clear things even more: `QPoint startPos(50,50),minimumDragDistance(11,11),finalPos(200,200); QTest::mousePress(window, Qt::LeftButton, {}, startPos);QTest::mouseMove(window, startPos-minimumDragDistance); QTest::mouseRelease(window, Qt::LeftButton, {}, startPos-minimumDragDistance+finalPos);`